# Local Storage and Conditional Mapping

Tags: reactjs

I am creating an array in local storage of leads created during that session that have an isClaimed status of false. here is my attempt at code

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import LeadContext from '../../context/Lead/leadContext'
import TodaysLeadItem from '../stacks/TodaysLeadItem'
import Leads from './Leads';

const TodaysLeads = () =>  {

const leadContext = useContext(LeadContext);
const { addLead, lead, todaysLeads } = leadContext
const { isClaimed } = lead

useEffect(()=>{
 if (!todaysLeads){
  localStorage.setItem('todaysLeads', todaysLeads);
 }
},[])

useEffect(()=>{

 todaysLeads.push(lead)

},[addLead,lead])


console.log(todaysLeads)

 return (
    <div style={leadStyle}>

     {todaysLeads.length > 0 ? todaysLeads.map((lead =>{if(lead.isClaimed === false){<TodaysLeadItem key={lead._id} lead={lead} />}})):''} 

    </div>
    );

    }
    const leadStyle = {
      display: 'grid',
      gridTemplateRows: 'repeat(10, 1fr)',
      gridGap: '.5rem'
    };



export default TodaysLeads
```

How do I make it so that the map only shows leads created in this session where isClaimed = false (its default setting)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a return statement in your map function

```
return <TodaysLeadItem key={lead._id} lead={lead} />
```

or

```
<div style={leadStyle}>
  {todaysLeads.length > 0
    ? todaysLeads.map(
        lead =>
          lead.isClaimed === false && (
            <TodaysLeadItem key={lead._id} lead={lead} />
          )
      )
    : ""}
</div>
```

Comment: the return didnt work... which is why i came here  i guess i should have fixed trhe code a little

Comment: please run this code and tell me what it logs ```<div style={leadStyle}>
      {todaysLeads.length > 0
        ? todaysLeads.map(lead => {
            console.log(lead);

            return (
              lead.isClaimed === false && (
                <TodaysLeadItem key={lead._id} lead={lead} />
              )
            );
          })
        : ""}
    </div>```

Comment: instead of deleting the item where isClaimed = true its duplicating it abd sending this error :

index.js:1406 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `5e50c633de81da3f547acedf`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Comment: is claimed type boolean? or it is ```isClaimed: 'true'``` and the error is because you data has the same keys, please change them to make them unique.

Comment: isClaimed is boolean

Comment: please create a simple codesandbox for me to see your code. https://codesandbox.io/s/